# Web page scraping in Delphi

Tags: delphi, web-scraping

DO you know a library for Web page scraping for Delphi. Like Beautiful Soup or Scrapy for Python ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, it's not for Delphi, but for FreePascal, since I do not have a recent Delphi version, but porting between them is supposed to be not so difficult.

Anyways, my [Internet Tools](http://www.benibela.de/sources_en.html#internettools) are probably the best Pascal web scraping library that are out there.

You can, e.g. print all links on a page with:

```
uses simpleinternet, xquery;

var a: IXQValue;
begin
  for a in process('http://stackoverflow.com', '//a/@href') do
    writeln(a.toString);
end.
```

They are platform independent; have full support for XPath 2, XQuery,  CSS 3 selectors (those are not so well tested through, XPath is better anyways) and pattern-matching; parse xml and html; and download over http and https.

Answer (score 1):

After the page is loaded with TWebBrowser component, query the TWebBrowser.Document property for the IHTMLDocument2 interface and then you can enumerate the elements.

You can getElementsById, getElementsByTagName, getElementsByName, for example:

```
var
  Elem: IHTMLElement;
begin
   Elem := GetElementById(WebBrowser1.Document, 'myid') as IHTMLElement;
end;
```

or get all HTML text and use any way you want, for example:

```
sourceHTML := WebBrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
sourceHTML.body.innerHTML;
```